# The Ext React renderer function if throwing the error below, I want to combine two fields from the record as a single column using the renderer

Tags: reactjs, extjs, extreact

```
<Grid store={store}>
    <Column
        text='Dispatch and Receipt Locations'
        flex={1]
        renderer={(value, record) => {
        return record.get('DispatchLocation') + ' to ' + record.get('ReceiptLocation')
        }}
    />
</Grid>
```

I am getting the below error:

> Uncaught Error: [Ext.create] Unrecognized class name / alias: widget.renderercell at
>   Object.create (ext.js:11776) at constructor.createCell (ext.js:82542) at
>   constructor.insertColumn (ext.js:82429) at constructor.addColumn (ext.js:82405) at
>   constructor.onAdded (ext.js:82401) at constructor.doAdd (ext.js:41374) at
>   constructor.add (ext.js:41339) at constructor.addDataItem (ext.js:70703) at
>   constructor.callParent (ext.js:10561) at constructor.addDataItem (ext.js:71606)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to require the renderercell package in `webpack.config.js` and need to be imported.

```
packages: ['ext-react-renderercell'],
```

or in Ext-React > 6 :

```
packages: ['renderercell']
```

Comment: Thanks for the response,

When adding the package renderercell i'm getting this error

`i [ext]: [ERR] Cannot satisfy requirements for "renderercell"!`
`i [ext]: [ERR]    The following versions cannot be satisfied: [ERR]       null: renderercell (No matches!)`
`i [ext]: [ERR] Cannot resolve package requirements`
`[ext]: Cannot satisfy requirements for "renderercell"!`

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: ext-webpack-plugin v7.0.2, 
Ext JS v7.2.0 Commercial Edition, 
Sencha Cmd v7.2.0.66, 
webpack v4.43.0, 
react v16.8.6

Comment: Is it included in package.json like `@sencha/ext-react-renderercell": "~7.0"`?. What `npm view @sencha/ext-react-renderercell` returned?

Comment: Thank you so much, it was missing in package.json so I had to do an npm install